# Testing promise in Angular 2 ngOnInit

Tags: jasmine, angular

I have an Angular 2 component I am trying to put under test, but I am having trouble because the data is set in the `ngOnInit` function, so is not immediately available in the unit test.

user-view.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

import {User} from './user';
import {UserService} from './user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-view',
  templateUrl: './components/users/view.html'
})
export class UserViewComponent implements OnInit {
  public user: User;

  constructor(
    private _routeParams: RouteParams,
    private _userService: UserService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const id: number = parseInt(this._routeParams.get('id'));

    this._userService
      .getUser(id)
      .then(user => {
        console.info(user);
        this.user = user;
      });
  }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

// mock-users is a static JS array
import {users} from './mock-users';
import {User} from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  getUsers() : Promise<User[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(users);
  }

  getUser(id: number) : Promise<User> {
    return Promise.resolve(users[id]);
  }
}
```

user-view.component.spec.ts:

```
import {
  beforeEachProviders,
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  injectAsync,
  TestComponentBuilder
} from 'angular2/testing';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {DOM} from 'angular2/src/platform/dom/dom_adapter';

import {UserViewComponent} from './user-view.component';

import {UserService} from './user.service';

export function main() {
  describe('User view component', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
      provide(RouteParams, { useValue: new RouteParams({ id: '0' }) }),
      UserService
    ]);

    it('should have a name', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
      return tcb.createAsync(UserViewComponent)
        .then((rootTC) => {
          spyOn(console, 'info');

          let uvDOMEl = rootTC.nativeElement;
          rootTC.detectChanges();

          expect(console.info).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
          expect(DOM.querySelectorAll(uvDOMEl, 'h2').length).toBe(0);
        });
    }));

  });
}
```

The route param is getting passed correctly, but the view hasn't changed before the tests are run. How do I set up a test that happens after the promise in ngOnInit is resolved?

Comment: At the moment I am moving my code from ngOnInit into the constructor, this allows tests to be run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return a `Promise` from `#ngOnInit`:

```ts
ngOnInit(): Promise<any> {
  const id: number = parseInt(this._routeParams.get('id'));

  return this._userService
    .getUser(id)
    .then(user => {
      console.info(user);
      this.user = user;
    });
}
```

I ran into the same issue a few days back, and found this to be the most workable solution. As far as I can tell, it doesn't impact anywhere else in the application; since `#ngOnInit` has no specified return type in the source's TypeScript, I doubt anything in the source code is expecting a return value from that.

Link to `OnInit`: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.6/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/interfaces.ts#L79-L122

### Edit

In your test, you'd return a new `Promise`:

```ts
it('should have a name', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
  // Create a new Promise to allow greater control over when the test finishes
  //
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tcb.createAsync(UserViewComponent)
      .then((rootTC) => {

        // Call ngOnInit manually and put your test inside the callback
        //
        rootTC.debugElement.componentInstance.ngOnInit().then(() => {
          spyOn(console, 'info');

          let uvDOMEl = rootTC.nativeElement;
          rootTC.detectChanges();

          expect(console.info).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
          expect(DOM.querySelectorAll(uvDOMEl, 'h2').length).toBe(0);

          // Test is done
          //
          resolve();
        });

      });
    }));

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was making the same silly mistake.

Answer (score 14):

IMO the best solution for this use case is to just make a *synchronous* mock service . You can't [use `fakeAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38258612/2587435) for this particular case [because of the XHR call for `templateUrl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8280). And personally I don't think the "hack" to [make `ngOnInit` return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35470740/2587435) is very elegant. And you should not have to call `ngOnInit` directly, as it should be called by the framework.

You should already be using mocks anyway, as you are only unit testing the component, and don't want to be dependent on the real service working correctly.

To make a service that is synchronous, simple return the service itself from whatever methods are being called. You can then add your `then` and `catch` (`subscribe` if you are using `Observable`) methods to the mock, so it acts like a `Promise`. For example

```
class MockService {
  data;
  error;

  getData() {
    return this;
  }

  then(callback) {
    if (!this.error) {
      callback(this.data);
    }
    return this;
  }

  catch(callback) {
    if (this.error) {
      callback(this.error);
    }
  }

  setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  setError(error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
}
```

This has a few benefits. For one it gives you a lot of control over the service during execution, so you can easily customize it's behavior. And of course it's all synchronous.

Here's another example.

A common thing you will see with components is the use of `ActivatedRoute` and subscribing to its params. This is asynchronous, and done inside the `ngOnInit`. What I tend to do with this is create a mock for both the `ActivatedRoute` *and* the `params` property. The `params` property will be a mock object and have some functionality that appears to the outside world like an observable.

```
export class MockParams {
  subscription: Subscription;
  error;

  constructor(private _parameters?: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this.subscription = new Subscription();
    spyOn(this.subscription, 'unsubscribe');
  }

  get params(): MockParams {
    return this;
  }

  subscribe(next: Function, error: Function): Subscription {
    if (this._parameters && !this.error) {
      next(this._parameters);
    }
    if (this.error) {
      error(this.error);
    }
    return this.subscription;
  }
}

export class MockActivatedRoute {
  constructor(public params: MockParams) {}
}
```

You can see we have a `subscribe` method that behaves like an `Observable#subscribe`. Another thing we do is spy on the `Subscription` so that we can test that it is destroyed. In most cases you will have unsubscribed inside your `ngOnDestroy`. To set up these mocks in your test you can just do something like

```
let mockParams: MockParams;

beforeEach(() => {
  mockParams = new MockParams({ id: 'one' });
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    declarations: [ TestComponent ],
    providers: [
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: new MockActivatedRoute(mockParams) }
    ]
  });
});
```

Now all the params are set for the route, and we have access to the mock params so we can set the error, and also check the subscription spy to make sure its been unsubscribed from.

If you look at the tests below, you will see that they are all synchronous tests. No need for `async` or `fakeAsync`, and it passes with flying colors.

Here is the complete test (using RC6)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  template: `
    <span *ngIf="id">{{ id }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="error">{{ error }}</span>
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: string;
  error: string;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this._route.params.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        this.id = params['id'];
      },
      (error) => {
        this.error = error;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

export class MockParams {
  subscription: Subscription;
  error;

  constructor(private _parameters?: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this.subscription = new Subscription();
    spyOn(this.subscription, 'unsubscribe');
  }

  get params(): MockParams {
    return this;
  }

  subscribe(next: Function, error: Function): Subscription {
    if (this._parameters && !this.error) {
      next(this._parameters);
    }
    if (this.error) {
      error(this.error);
    }
    return this.subscription;
  }
}

export class MockActivatedRoute {
  constructor(public params: MockParams) {}
}

describe('component: TestComponent', () => {
  let mockParams: MockParams;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockParams = new MockParams({ id: 'one' });
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ CommonModule ],
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: new MockActivatedRoute(mockParams) }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should set the id on success', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    let spanEls: DebugElement[] = debugEl.queryAll(By.css('span'));
    expect(spanEls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(spanEls[0].nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe('one');
  });

  it('should set the error on failure', () => {
    mockParams.error = 'Something went wrong';
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    let spanEls: DebugElement[] = debugEl.queryAll(By.css('span'));
    expect(spanEls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(spanEls[0].nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe('Something went wrong');
  });

  it('should unsubscribe when component is destroyed', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.destroy();
    expect(mockParams.subscription.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, hopefully this will be helpful for anyone else having the problem. The use of `ngOnInit` is because that was what was in the documentation at the time.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, here is how I managed to fix it. I had to use fakeAsync and tick.

```
fakeAsync(
      inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        tcb
        .overrideProviders(UsersComponent, [
          { provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService }
        ])
        .createAsync(UsersComponent)
        .then(fixture => {
          fixture.autoDetectChanges(true);
          let component = <UsersComponent>fixture.componentInstance;
          component.ngOnInit();
          flushMicrotasks();
          let element = <HTMLElement>fixture.nativeElement;
          let items = element.querySelectorAll('li');
          console.log(items);
        });
      })
    )
```

Comment: How do you deal with the `templateUrl` xhr call? As it's not allowed inside the `fakeAsync`.

Comment: @YuanfeiZhu [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39445420/2587435)

Comment: I am not using XHR as I am mocking my `fetch` by returning a promise, However this is still async and using fakeAsync solved it for me. To be noted, I had to write `fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();`