# Angular 2 RC5 Testing Promises in ngOnInit Not Working

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing, angular-rc5

I am trying to test a structural directive named MyDirective with Jasmine. The Angular version used is RC5.

```
// Part of the MyDirective class

@Directive({selector: '[myDirective]'})
export class MyDirective {
    constructor(protected templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                protected viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
                protected myService: MyService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getData()
            .then((data) => {
                if (!MyService.isValid(data)) {
                    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                } else {
                    this.viewContainer.clear();
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            });
    }
}
```

The getData method is overwritten in the MockService class whereas the isValid method (a static method of MyService) is called directly, which checks the validity of the data.

```
// Part of the Jasmine unit test class for the MyDirective class

@Component({
    selector: 'test-cmp', template: '', directives: [MyDirective]
})
class TestComponent {}

class MockService {
    mockResponse: MyResponse = {valid date goes here};
    mockInvalidResponse: MyResponse = {};

    getData() {
        if (booleanCondition) {
            return Promise.resolve(this.mockResponse);
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(this.mockInvalidResponse);
        }
    }
}

describe('MyDirective', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            providers: [
                {provide: MyService, useClass: MockService},
                TemplateRef,
                ViewContainerRef
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should remove the target DOM element when the condition is true', async(() => {
        booleanCondition = true;
        const template =
             '<div><div *myDirective><span>Hi</span></div></div>';

        TestBed.overrideComponent(TestComponent, {set: {template: template}});
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(getDOM().querySelectorAll(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement, 'span').length).toEqual(0);
    }));

    it('should contain the target DOM element when the condition is false', async(() => {
        booleanCondition = false;
        const template =
             '<div><div *myDirective><span>Hi</span></div></div>';

        TestBed.overrideComponent(TestComponent, {set: {template: template}});
        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // The 'expect' bellow fails because the value is 0 for some reason
        expect(getDOM().querySelectorAll(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement, 'span').length).toEqual(1);
    }));
});
```

The second `it` is supposed to create a case in which the span element is in the DOM, but it does not. I checked to see if it goes to the first condition in the if statement like this:

```
if (!MyService.isValid(data)) {
        console.log('the first if condition is read.');
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
        this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
}
```

And it logs it. So, it should keep the element in the DOM, but I can't find a way to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It because a `Promise` (the one returned from `getData`) is asynchronous. So all the synchronous activity gets handled ahead of the `Promise` activity. Even though `ngOnInit` is called, the `Promise` is resolved asynchronously.

There are a couple options that I usually use for this type thing.

One option is to use [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/fakeAsync-function.html) instead of `async`. This allows you to call `tick` to allow for asynchronous actions to complete synchronously

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('... when the condition is false', fakeAsync(() => {
  const template = '<div><div *myDirective><span>Hi</span></div></div>';

  TestBed.overrideComponent(TestComponent, { set: { template: template } });
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // tick can also be called with a millisecond delay argument `tick(1000)`
  tick();          
  expect(getDOM().querySelectorAll(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement, 'span').length)
    .toEqual(1);
}));
```

Another options is to make the mocked service synchronous. You can easily do that by making the call to `getData()` return the service itself, and add a `then` and `catch` method to the service. For example

```
class MockMyService {
  data;
  error;

  getData() {
    return this;
  }

  then(callback) {
    if (!this.error) {
      callback('mockData');
    }
    return this;
  }

  catch(callback) {
    if (this.error) {
      callback(this.error);
    }
  }

  setData(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  setError(error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that it gives you more control over the service during the test execution. This is also very useful when testing components that use `templateUrl`. [XHR calls can't be made in a `fakeAsync`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8280), so using that is not an option. This is where the synchronous mock service comes in use.

You can either inject the service to your `it` test cases or you can just keep a variable in you test and set it up something like

```
let mockMyService: MockMyService;

beforeEach(() => {
  mockMyService = new MockMyService();
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: MyService, useValue: mockMyService }
    ]
  });
});
```

---

**Note:** You'll also want to fix your *passing* test, as your current test is not valid for reasons mentioned above.

---

**See Also:**

- My post in [Testing promise in Angular2 ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445420/2587435) for an example of mocking `ActivatedRoute` to work synchronously when testing a component.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet! I used the first of your two solutions, and it worked as expected. Do you happen to know the difference between using Jasmine's `done()` (passing the done parameter) and using  [async](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/async-function.html)? [Angular's test source code](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/async-function.html) uses `async()` instead of `done()`. I am trying to understand how `async()` recognizes all asynchronous calls are done. This might be worth another full question...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with Zones. I am still learning zones, but I from what I currently understand, zones polyfill asynchronous methods like `setTimout` and such, to the point where the zone knows about all the asynchronous calls made in that zone. The zone keeps a record of all these pending tasks. Check [this out](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/)

Comment: If you look at the [source for `async`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/testing/async.ts), you see a lot of zone stuff going on. You'll also see there that `async` actually does call `done` when in a jasmine environment

Comment: Knowing that it might have to do with Zones made me feel better. Thanks! I will look into it when necessary. `async` actually calling `done` makes a lot of sense.