# Test an async PipeTransform

Tags: asynchronous, angular, jasmine, angular2-testing, angular2-pipe

#### Context

I have a basic `PipeTransform`, expect the fact that it is async. Why? because I have my own i18n service (because of parsing, pluralization and other constraints, I did my own) and it returns a `Promise<string>`:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "i18n",
    pure: false
})
export class I18nPipe implements PipeTransform {

    private done = false;

    constructor(private i18n:I18n) {
    }

    value:string;

    transform(value:string, args:I18nPipeArgs):string {
        if(this.done){
            return this.value;
        }
        if (args.plural) {
            this.i18n.getPlural(args.key, args.plural, value, args.variables, args.domain).then((res) => {
                this.value = res;
                this.done = true;
            });
        }
        this.i18n.get(args.key, value, args.variables, args.domain).then((res) => {
            this.done = true;
            this.value = res;
        });
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

This pipe works well, because the only delayed call is the very first one (the `I18nService` uses lazy loading, it loads JSON data only if the key is not found, so basically, the first call will be delayed, the other ones are instant but still async).

#### Problem

I can't figure out how to test this pipe using `Jasmine`, since it is working inside a component I know it works, but the goal here is to get this fully tested using jasmine, this way I can add it to a CI routine.

The above test:

```
describe("Pipe test", () => {

        it("can call I18n.get.", async(inject([I18n], (i18n:I18n) => {
            let pipe = new I18nPipe(i18n);
            expect(pipe.transform("nope", {key: 'test', domain: 'test domain'})).toBe("test value");
        })));
});
```

Fails because since the result given by the `I18nService` is async, the returned value is undefined in a sync logic.

> I18n Pipe test can call I18n.get. FAILED
>
> Expected undefined to be 'test value'.

EDIT: One way to do it would be to use `setTimeout` but I want a prettier solution, to avoid adding `setTimeout(myAssertion, 100)` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fakeAsync` from `@angular/core/testing`. It allows you to call `tick()`, which will wait for all currently queued asynchronous tasks to complete before continuing. This gives the illusion of the actions being synchronous. Right after the call to `tick()` we can write our expectations.

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

it("can call I18n.get.", fakeAsync(inject([I18n], (i18n:I18n) => {
  let pipe = new I18nPipe(i18n);
  let result = pipe.transform("nope", {key: 'test', domain: 'test domain'});
  tick();
  expect(result).toBe("test value");
})));
```

So when should we use `fakeAsync` and when should we use `async`? This is the rule of thumb that I go by (most of the time). When we are making asynchronous calls *inside* the test, this is when we should use `async`. `async` allows to test to continue until all asynchronous calls are complete. For example

```
it('..', async(() => {
  let service = new Servce();
  service.doSomething().then(result => {
    expect(result).toBe('hello');
  });
});
```

In a non `async` test, the expectation would never occur, as the test would complete before the asynchronous resolution of the promise. With the call to `async`, the test gets wrapped in a zone, which keeps track of all asynchronous tasks, and waits for them to complete.

Use `fakeAsync` when the asynchronous behavior is outside the control of the test (like in your case is going on in the pipe). Here we can force/wait for it to complete with the call to `tick()`. `tick` can also be passed a millisecond delay to allow more time to pass if needed.

Another option is to mock the service and make it synchronous, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39437189/2587435). When unit testing, if your components in test are dependent on heavy logic in the service, then the component in test is at the mercy of that service working correctly, which kinda defeats the purpose of a "unit" test. Mocking makes sense in a lot of cases.

Comment: Another involved issue was that the pipe's transform is called only once, so the return is basically always undefined. I fixed that by making a recursive method in my test file that allows me to call a pipe transform as long as I have undefined as result, with a maxium call stack.