# How do I unit test with a subscribe in Angular5?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, observable

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataplansDetails} from '../../models/dataplans-details';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: 'jsonform',
  templateUrl: './jsonform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jsonform.component.scss']

})
export class JsonformComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() dataplanDetails: any;
  public layout: any = [];
  public schema: any = {};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataplanDetails.subscribe(res => {
      const fileSchema = JSON.parse(res.details.submissionFileSchema)

      const formLayout = fileSchema["layout"]
      this.schema = {
        type: "object",
        properties: fileSchema["properties"]
      }

      const schemaKeys = Object.keys(this.schema["properties"])
```

This is my component. It has a `subscribe` that I'm having trouble unit testing. My test includes:

```
fdescribe('JsonformComponent', () => {
  let component: JsonformComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<JsonformComponent>;
  const mockObservable = new Subject();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {provide: Store, useClass: StoreStub}
      ],
      imports: [],
      declarations: [JsonformComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JsonformComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component['dataplanDetals'] = mockObservable
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should not set layout if there are no properties', () => {
    mockObservable.next({test: 'data'})


    component.parseSchema('{"layout": [], "properties": {}}')
    // component.properties = false
    expect(component.schema).toEqual({})
    expect(component.layout).toEqual([])
  })

  // it('should set the layout to have the keys', () => {
  //   component.properties = {}
  // })
});
```

I'm getting an error: `Failed: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.dataplanDetails.subscribe')`

How do I trigger the subscribe from the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Pull the `subscribe` callback into it's own method and test it directly.

2) Mock the emission of `dataplanDetails`. Ex:

```
const mockObservable = new Subject();
component['dataplanDetails'] = mockObservable;
mockObservable.next({ test: 'data' });
...now you should hit the `subscribe` block
```

Comment: Still didn't hit `subscribe`. Also, in the `ngOnInit`, `console.log(this.dataplanDetails)` returns `undefined`

Comment: Set the `@Input()` in your `beforeEach` block. You may also need to explicitly call `ngOnInit` there as well.

Comment: `ngOnInit` seems to be called automatically. How do I set the `@Input()`?

Comment: By setting the value of `dataplanDetails` on the component before `ngOnInit` runs. It's in my second example.

Comment: I updated my original post. Is this what you had described?

Comment: Sort of. Place it before the `detectChanges` line. So it becomes:

    `component['dataplanDetals'] = mockObservable;
    fixture.detectChanges();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168584/discussion-between-shamoon-and-bc1105).

Answer (score 0):

[Angular 2 RC5 Testing Promises in ngOnInit Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436230/angular-2-rc5-testing-promises-in-ngoninit-not-working)

I feel like testing if the subscription is defined should be enough, or you might trigger the loadingObservable to switch isLoading to either true or false.

If you're using **loadingObservable** try to switch to **isLoading** and set it to true/false