# How to mock formControl value getTime() in unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am trying to unit test a formControl's getTime(). I am getting an error

> .getTime is not a function.

A snippet of the component file looks like:

```
import {FormControl} from @angular/forms;
@component({ 
  selector: 'lorem-ipsum',
  templateUrl: './lorem-ipsum.html'
})

export class LoremIpsumComponent implements OnInIt {
  .....
  ...
  ..
  .
  magazineSubscriptionFrom = new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true});
  magazineSubscriptionTo = new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true});

  constructor (
    ....
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  verifySubscription() {
    let test1 = this.magazineSubscriptionFrom.value.getTime();
    ...
    ..
    .
  }
```

Comment: Can you also post your test code

Comment: @HDJEMAI ... tq for formatting.... I will do a better job next time

Comment: May be you can try to use [spyOnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928209/how-to-get-jasmines-spyonproperty-to-work)

Comment: ``spyOnProperty(component.magazineSubscriptionFrom, 'value', 'get').and.returnValue(your date value here)`` ?

Comment: take a look here, it may help as well: [How to unit test a FormControl in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481324/how-to-unit-test-a-formcontrol-in-angular2)

Comment: It is as below :                                                                It(‘should verifySubscription , () => {                           Component.magazineSubscription.setValue(‘’);            fixture.DetectChanges();                                         Component.verifySubscription();                               Expect(somevalue in verifySubscription fn).toBeTruthy;                                                                   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the initial value of `magazineSubscriptionFrom` is `''` since your are setting it in your `constructor` using line:

```
magazineSubscriptionFrom = new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true});
```

When you try to call `getTime()` on it, it will give you the error because `getTime()` is a function for `Date`. So you need a `Date` value in in your form control. You also need to convert the string value of your form control to Date in order for `getTime()` to work

You need to change line:

```
let test1 = this.magazineSubscriptionFrom.value.getTime();
```

to

```
let test1 = new Date(this.magazineSubscriptionFrom.value).getTime();
```

Now in your test you need to set the valid date using `setValue`

```
It is as below : It(‘should verifySubscription , () => { 
  Component.magazineSubscription.setValue(new Date()); <- set valid date here
  
  fixture.DetectChanges(); 
  
  Component.verifySubscription();
  Expect(somevalue in verifySubscription fn).toBeTruthy;
}
```

Also change it for `magazineSubscriptionTo` control.