# unit-testing for values set async in ngOnInit() function of an angular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript

I'm trying to unit-test an array that is set from an async service in the ngOnInit() function of my component.

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[] = [];

  constructor(public todoService: TodoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todoService.getTodos()
      .then(todos => this.todos = todos.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

When I try to test this with a function like that:

```js
  it('should load four todos for dashboard', function(done) {
    expect(component.todos.length).toEqual(4);
  });
```

I get an error that 0 is not equal to 4, as the promise is not resolved yet. The only way I could get this to work is by making the service public and running "dirty" code like that:

```js
  it('should load four todos for dashboard', function(done) {
    var todos = component.todoService.getTodos();
    todos.then(x => {
      expect(x.length).toEqual(6);
      expect(component.todos.length).toEqual(4)
    });
    done();
  });
```

But there sure is a better and cleaner way to do this, so any suggestings for improvements are welcome!

**Edit 1:** After the hint of dbandstra, which points in the right direction, I came up with this code:

```js
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  beforeEach( async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent, EmptyComponent,
        RouterLinkStubDirective, RouterOutletStubComponent
      ],
      providers: [{provide: TodoService, useClass: FakeTodoService}]
    })
      .overrideComponent(TodoSearchComponent, EmptyComponent)
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
        comp    = fixture.componentInstance;
      });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    // TodoService actually injected into the component
    let todoService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TodoService);

    let spy = spyOn(todoService, 'getTodos')
      .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(todos));

    // trigger initial data binding
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should load four todos for dashboard', () => {
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => { // wait for async getTodos
      fixture.detectChanges();        // update view with todos
      expect(comp.todos.length).toEqual(4);
    });
  })
});
```

This works like a charm, thanks!

**Edit 2:** I also got it to work with the suggested solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445420/3368833 by making the fake service synchronous like this:

```js
class TodoServiceMock{
  private data: Todo[];

  getTodos() {
    let todos = [ ...insert fake data here... ];
    this.data = todos;
    return this;
  }

  then(callback) {
    callback(this.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Explained here (their example is almost identical to your code)  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-async-service

Comment: The `whenStable` is wat fixed my async init tests, thanks for the code example!

Comment: You often can also use the `fakeAsync` zone and `tick` instead of whenStable. It's documented here: https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync#description

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

`dashboard.component.ts`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  /* We don't need to set an empty array here */
  todos: Todo[];

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.todoService.getTodos()
      .then(todos => this.todos = todos.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

and `dashboard.component.spec.ts`:

```js
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;

  let todoService: TodoService;

  const todos = [
    { id: 'id1' },
    { id: 'id2' },
    { id: 'id3' },
    { id: 'id4' },
    { id: 'id5' },
    { id: 'id6' },
  ] as Todo[];

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [DashboardComponent],
        providers: [
          /* Stub the TodoService as empty object */
          { provide: TodoService, useValue: {} },
        ],
      })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  /**
   * Creating the component instance in another beforeEach()
   * to decompose module configuration and setting values.
   */
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    /* Injecting the TodoService and mocking used methods. */
    todoService = TestBed.inject(TodoService);
    todoService.getTodos = jasmine.createSpy('getTodos').and.resolveTo(todos);
  });

  it('should create an instance of the component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('#ngOnInit', () => {
    /* Using fakeAsync for having the ability to wait for async operation. */
    it('should load four todos for dashboard', fakeAsync(() => {
      /* Running ngOnInit by calling the first detection of changes. */
      fixture.detectChanges();

      /**
       * Waiting for .then() method response,
       * because we cannot check the result immediately after running ngOnInit,
       * it's promises, not primitive code.
       */
      tick();

      /**
       * We use toBe() in comparing primitive types.
       * toEqual() is used for comparing not primitive types - objects, arrays, etc.
       */
      expect(component.todos.length).toBe(4);
    }));
  });
});
```

Recommended resource for learning Jasmine in Angular:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/jasmine-and-karma/